# How can you change the timezone in AppEngine's AppStats?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, timezone, appstats

I'm using Google AppEngine (python) and my application logs use UTC.  My AppStats however are returning what looks like PST.

How can I change the timezone used for AppStats to UTC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your appengine_config.py, set

```
appstats_TZOFFSET = 0
```

to display times in UTC. For other timezones set it to the number of seconds west of UTC.

Answer (score 1):

http://timezones.appspot.com/ might be helpful  to you.